# How to access url params in sapper outside of preload function?

Tags: url, parameters, svelte

In Sapper, AFAIK from documentation. The only way to access URL params are through `preload()` function, from which params are available inside `params` object.

The thing is that I want to access these params ouside of `preload()` function. From an eagle eye view of documentation. I don't / can't see the solution to my problem / requirement.

I have tried setting a property for url param inside `data()`. But it seems `preload()` has no access to `data` whether getting wise or setting wise. *It is not meant for those things.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<script>
import { stores } from "@sapper/app";

const { page } = stores();
const { slug } = $page.params;
</script>
```

https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs/#Stores

Answer (score 1):

If you are using v3 Svelte and latest alpha of Sapper, import page which is now provided as a store.

```
import { page } from '@sapper/app';

const  {slug} = $page.params;
```

Comment: This would be great, but it doesn't seem to work for me. What version of Sapper exactly are you using?

Comment: This was for an older version of Sapper (latest at time of answer). Accepted answer is the right way to do it now.